# substitute/disable control components for development/testing

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, testing, visual-studio-2005

I have a VB form that contains controls for interfacing with some hardware (video cameras, motors, etc) on the machine it is to be deployed on, but I'm usually not at the location of said machine (it's a 3-hour drive away).  I'm trying to work on the project while on my laptop, but obviously the controls will generate all sorts of errors since they can't talk to the hardware.

I was thinking of replacing the control types with my own mock control classes, then use #if directives to control whether I'm building for the real machine or my test machine.  Problem is, some of the affected code is in the form designer-generated code section; the form designer automatically tries to "correct" my changes, so I'd have to manually put them back all the time, and try to remember not to commit the form designer's edits into version control.

Any suggestions on how I can get around this problem, or perhaps a different approach so I (and my colleagues) can work while away from the site?

I'm working in VB2005.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Interface to solve this problem. Suppose `IHardware` is the interface, define all the functionality you require from video camera etc here. Now implement this interface in separate class library. This library will handle all the calls to your hardware code. Say this is `WorkLibrary`. Now in the form you will use this interface to make calls to your `WorkLibrary`.

Interface

```
interface IHardware
{
    void Load(); //Example
}
```

Class Library

```
class WorkClass : IHardware
{
    public void Load()
    {
    }
}
```

Inside your form, to call `Load` method, you will do

```
//Fully Qualified name of the WorkClass, you can store this in config file also
string provider = "WorkLibrary.WorkClass, WorkLibrary";
IHardware hardWare = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(provider, true));
hardWare.Load();
```

In this approach you don't have to refer `WorkLibrary.dll` in your form project, you will just need to put it inside `debug` or `release` folder.

This way you can decouple your hardware specific things completely.

More advantage of this can be

- You can write different libraries for different hardware.
- You can test these libraries independent of the consumer.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to use the Inversion Of Control pattern. It is a pattern where you create interfaces to define the methods needed by a class and then you can create two objects (or more), the 'real' one or the mock.

Read more [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control)